# Difference between L298 and L298N motor driver

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, l298n

I was planning to buy a motor driver for my project purpose, but I don't understand which motor driver will suit my purpose. As there are two motor drivers available online. Can someone explain me the main difference between the two :

L298N : https://www.amazon.in/L298N-Based-Motor-Driver-Module/dp/B01N1H97CL

L298 : https://www.amazon.in/Robodo-L298-Motor-Driver-Module/dp/B00N4KWYDE?tag=googinhydr18418-21

Comment: Have you looked into the datasheet?

Comment: L298 is the name of the chip. The most often used variant is the L298N. The so called Multiwatt L298.  I would say, both boards use the same chip. L298N. The other variant are L298HW and L298P (horizontal Multiwatt and SOIC packaging).

Comment: The chip itself can drive up to 4A but the boards may differ. The L298N called board is specified with 2 Ampere.  The L298 called board is described with 2A too.

Comment: Those are exactly the same boards just viewed from different angles.